# CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap Speed and Optimization

Tags: c#, wcf, appdomain

I'm working on a project where we have to wrap some legacy code that contains a lot of C# static variables into a WCF service. As you can imagine, this is a nightmare for a WCF service where requests should be state-less.

Without a major rewrite the best solution I can come up with is to execute the legacy code in a separate AppDomain so it is thread safe and I used CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap() to achieve this.

I got the code working but the problem is it's pretty slow because now for every single WCF request it has to reload all 20+ DLLs into a AppDomain before the code even start executing.

I'm just wondering does anyone know how to optimize CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap()? For example, is there anyway I can pre-load all assemblies without loading the class in so the static variables will be reset everytime a request comes in?

Cheers,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Short of knowing how you could do exactly what you are asking for, at least I want to share my thoughts on the matter:

- Can you go for session state? This does not scale horribly well, but if you could load an AppDomain for each session you could get good responsiveness. It depends how many concurrent users you have.
- Can you have some other box that serves as a pool of AppDomains, thereby separating the cost of creating the AppDomain from serving the request?
- Is it kind of deterministic how all the statics come together? Are they maybe lazily loaded? Maybe with some reflection or with dynamic methods you could manage to erase static state after the request.